# return a string where each digit is repeated a number of times equals to its value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem: Given a string made of digits [0-9], return a string where each digit is repeated a number of times equals to its value. I did the repetition of numbers, how next - I don’t know.

```
function explode(s) {
  for (let i=0; i < s.length; i++){
    let y = s[i].repeat(s[i]);
    
    console.log(y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were only missing a result string to collect the parts

```js
function explode(input) {
  let result = '';
  let s = input.toString();  // So that input can also be a number
  for (let i=0; i < s.length; i++){
    let y = s[i].repeat(s[i]);
    result += y;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is good at *coercing* numbers to string and vice versa but I prefer to make clear when a numerical character is being treated as a number and when it is intended to be a string.

My snippet tests processing of numbers, string representations of numbers, strings having mixtures of number and letter characters, and letter strings.

it makes use of `array.split()` to for the character array, `array.map()` to process the characters (including `parseInt` to formally change the character to a number when used as the argument the `string.repeat()`, and `array.join()` to return the desired numeric string after processing:

```js
let number = 6789;
let numberString = "12345";
let badNum = "3bad2Number";
let noNum = "justLetters";

console.log(expandNums(number));
console.log(expandNums(numberString));
console.log(expandNums(badNum));
console.log(expandNums(noNum));

function expandNums(numOrString) {
  let numString = numOrString.toString();
  let chars = numString.split('');
  let processed = chars.map(char => char.repeat(parseInt(char)));
  
return processed.join('');
} // end function expandNums
```

The function performs well under all use situations tested, so is unlikely to throw an error if a bad argument is passes. It also does a good job with the mixed letter/number example.